# Displaying and formatting specific lines before and after a match in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, markdown

I am working with a file structured like this:

```
Title1
- Quote

this is a quote
==========
Title1
- Note

this is a note
==========
Title1
- Quote

this is another quote
==========
Title1
- Note

this is another note
```

Each Title (Title1 Title2..) contains hundreds of quotes and some of those quotes have notes following them. Each specific note and quote is exactly 1 line. For a given Title I want to display "this is a quote" followed by "this is a note":

```
this is a quote
   >> this is a note
--
this is another quote
   >> this is another note
```

I came up with something like this:

`grep -C 6 "Title1" | grep -B 3 -A 2 "Note" | egrep -v "Title1|=====|Note"`

I got this result :

```
this is a quote

this is a note
--
this is another quote

this is another note
```

How do I format the text to achieve the results above?
I am still new to Bash and wondering if there's a more efficient way to achieve  this? I was experimenting with sed for this but I couldn't get it to work.
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Edit:
I should have been clearer about this. I'd like to clarify that "this is a quote" and "this is a note" contain different strings each time, while "Quote" and "Note" are the same throughout the file.

Comment: That seems a bit complicated for a "simple" tool like grep or sed. You might have to look into other tools such as awk of bash programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using `awk` is an option:

```
awk -v title="Title1" '$0~title{f=1} /Quote/&&f==1{q=1} /Note/&&f==1{n=1} /====/{f=0;q=0;n=0} /^$/ && f==1 && q==1 {getline; print} /^$/ && f==1 && n==1 {getline; printf "%6s %s\n",">>",$0}' src.dat
this is a quote
    >> this is a note
this is another quote
    >> this is another note
```

`-v title="Title1"` pass the target title as a variable to awk

`$0~title{f=1}` set flag 'f' if current line matches target title.

`/Quote/&&f==1{q=1}` set quote flag 'q' if title flag is set and current line matches 'Quote'.

`/Note/&&f==1{n=1}` set note flag 'n' if title flag is set and current line matches 'Note'.

`/^$/ && f==1 && q==1 {getline; print}` if current line is empty and title and quote flags are set, get the next line and print.

`/^$/ && f==1 && n==1 {getline; printf "%6s %s\n",">>",$0}'`. if current line is empty and title and note flags are set, get the next line and print it as formatted output.

`/====/{f=0;q=0;n=0}` clear flags if current line matches '===='.

---

contents of src.dat file used for testing:

```
Title1
- Quote

this is a quote
==========
Title1
- Note

this is a note
==========
Title1
- Quote

this is another quote
==========
Title1
- Note

this is another note
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! It's a useful command that would prove really handy but it doesn't solve this particular problem. I should have been clearer in the post but "this is a quote" and "this is a note" are different each time. They are notes and quotes that I want to extract that's why I was looking to get them though their position with regards to the other stable "Title" "Quote" and "Note"

Comment: Updated answer per your clarification.

Comment: Thank you! it worked. Time for me to learn some more awk